# Centerline properties of a contour shape by using center of mass?

Tags: image, matlab

I have a contour plot rendered from an image and I would like to plot the property profile along the centerline of the contour. The problem is that the centerline axis changings per each image so I would like to automate it instead of doing it by hand.

I've tried doing it manually, where I would literally pull up the image and and find the centerline on the x-axis.

```
center_temp = T_RG(:,395); % adjust x-axis centerline
y_pixels= 1:size(T_RG,1); %1200
x_pixels= 1:size(T_RG,2); %1600
pixelsize = .00586; %mm
x_dist = x_pixels.*pixelsize;
y_dist = y_pixels.*pixelsize;

plot(y_pixels,movmean(center_temp,10),'LineWidth',1)
title('Centerline Temperature Profile','fontname','helvetica','fontsize',12)
xlabel('Distance (mm)','fontname','helvetica','fontsize',12);
ylabel('Temperature (K)','fontname','helvetica','fontsize',12);
centerline_temps(:,ii) = center_temp;
```

[Example of what the image looks like and where i want to find the centerline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pARQd.png)

Comment: look into `regionprops` https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html